# set file input value iframe transport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to send a user selected file via a hidden iFrame.  After retrieving the file itself from a change event, I cannot add the file to a dynamically created form using something like this:

```
   var fileInput = document.createElement('input');
       fileInput.type = 'file';
       fileInput.name = paramName;
       fileInput.value = file;
```

How might I accomplish this?

Thanks.

I'm thinking i'm going to have to do something with the original field, but am wondering if there is a way where I don't have to.

Comment: This is probably a security feature (for the user).

Comment: yeah, I read about that.  But I saw that the formData object can work with files directly, which works fine when I'm using ajax, and was wondering if there is a way to make it work in the manner above.  My solution, which may be the only one, is to just append the original input field to the iframe form.